# Unable to add text to some PDFs with PyMuPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I'm writing a Python (v3.11) script, using the library PyMuPDF, to write some text to PDF.
The script works fine with some PDFs, but with others it doesn't write the text. It doesn't show any errors, the output file is created, but without the text added.

Here is the script:

```py
import fitz

def processPdf(input_file, output_file, text):
    doc = fitz.open(input_file)
    page = doc.load_page(0)

    x = 100
    y = 100

    insertText(page, text, x, y)
    #insertTextbox(page, text, x, y)

    doc.save(output_file)
    doc.close()

def insertText(page, text, x, y):
    p = fitz.Point(x, y)
    page.insert_text(
            p,
            text,
            fontname = "helv",
            fontsize = 11,
            color = (1, 0, 0)
    )

def insertTextbox(page, text, x, y):
    rect = (x, y, x+200, y+200)
    page.draw_rect(rect, color=(0.25, 1, 0, 0.25))
    rc = page.insert_textbox(
            rect,
            text,
            fontname = "helv",
            fontsize = 11,
            align = 1
    )

processPdf("input_file.pdf", "output_file.pdf", "123")
```

I tried both methods `insert_text` and `insert_textbox`, but neither works.

1. The PDF is not write protected or password protected.
2. As you can see, I used small values as coordinates, so to be sure the text will be inserted inside the margins of a normal PDF (the PDFs are A4 papersize).
3. The text is a simple "123", so it doesn't contain special characters.
4. I've already used the method `doc.get_layers()` to check if there are layers that can cover the inserted text and there are none.

What can I check more?

Thank you all in advance.

Edit: I tried to modify the PDF's content with an app called UPDF, in order to hide the sensible content and share the problematic file with you. Of course, after saving the file (using the function Flatten and Save of UPDF), my script was able to write the "123" text in the modified file. What could have UPDF changed in the problematic file to let it be modified by my script (I only used UPDF to replace some text with "---" and put black squares on a couple of images)?

Comment: Can you provide an example input PDF and output PDF file, where the text fails to show?

Comment: @johnwhitington, I'm sorry, but these PDFs have sensible content of my company and even if I try to hide it with shapes, the new exported PDF still has the content not visible, but selectable. I'll try a way to share this file.

Comment: @KJ no no, I was replying to jognwhitington about the possibility to share the PDF file. I can't do it because i can't completely hide the sensible content of the PDF.

Comment: Can you **extract** the inserted text from the output PDF? Did you try to guard against un-wrapped geometry changes using `page.clean_contents()` or `page.wrap_contents()`? Maybe your text landed at unexpected places because some mirroring or scaling matrix was still active (= not properly wrapped in `q`/`Q` stacking commands?

Comment: @JorjMcKie It worked!! Calling `page.clean_contents()` before writing the text does the job! Thank you, mate. Only one thing: just calling the `clean_contents`, the output file is a 5.3MB, starting from a 148KB input file. Is there a way to keep the file smaller?

Comment: @Ma3x - you should save the file using a couple of compression options: `doc.save(filename, garbage=3, deflate=True)`. The reason being that page content cleaning generates new appearance streams for each of the respective pages. The old versions however remain in the file - if you don't explicitely get rid of them this way.

Comment: @JorjMcKie Again, works perfectly. Thank you! You should place your 2 comments as an answer, so I can accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of PDF pages is generated by a special type of source code contained in a page's `/Contents` objects (0 to many). Coordinates of objects (like text or vector graphics) given in this source may be under control of matrices, which change the coordinate system - for example from one having the page bottom-left as point (0,0) to one having top-left being point (0,0).

It is recommended practice to "localize" the scope of these coordinate system changes by putting them within a pair of stacking (`q`) / unstacking (`Q`) commands. The effect being that later insertions (coming after the `Q`) can rely on the standard PDF coordinate system being in place.

If a matrix is not wrapped like this, then it remains active for ever, and later insertions - not being aware of this - will land at wrong places. As it has happened here.

To prevent this, `page.clean_contents()` or `page.wrap_contents()` can be used for a PDF page. The first method does an extensive (and expensive) source syntax cleaning, plus cleaning activities that go far beyond. Encapsulating matrices is just a side benefit.
The method generates one single, completely new `/Contents` for the page and renders all the old ones unused. As is usual with PDF updates old, unused object physically remain present in the file, and will only be removed if the document is saved using compression algorithms and actually rebuilding it:

```py
# typical save method:
doc.save(filename,
    garbage=3,  # detect / omit unused objects, rebuild the XREF table
    deflate=True,  # compress object streams where possible
    ...)
```

The other method, `page.wrap_contents()` does a lot less: it simply puts the stacking command `"q"` in front of all existing `/Contents` objects and the unstacking `"Q"` at the end.
This often (but not always!) is sufficient to solve your issue. The advantage is the economical behavior in terms of ***space*** (suitable for ***incremental*** saves, no compression or garbage collection required) and execution ***time***: insertion of the two commands is a microsecond business.

For more background, the documentation should be consulted [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-common-issues-and-their-solutions.html#misplaced-item-insertions-on-pdf-pages).